# JS Variable not available outside function

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, domparser

I have a little problem with a variable in my code.

I'm having a variable which gets declaired outside the function but then can not be accessed after it.

So first you input a file which is combined with this code:

```
input.addEventListener("change", sefunction);
```

Now this file (which is a HTML-file) should get parsed into a string:

```
var htmlInput;
var inputFile = "";
function sefunction() {
if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var myFile = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
        inputFile = e.target.result;
        htmlInput = new DOMParser().parseFromString(inputFile, "text/html").documentElement;
        console.log(htmlInput);            //WORKING FINE
        });
    reader.readAsBinaryString(myFile);
    document.getElementById("starten").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("myFile").disabled = true;
    console.log(htmlInput);                //NOT WORKING
    initialisation2();
  };   
};
```

Then, to test it, I want to console.log the `htmlInput`:

```
function initialisation2() {
    console.log(htmlInput);                //NOT WORKING
}
```

Now what happens: The first `console.log` gives me the content of `htmlInput`. The second and the third (in `initialisation2()`) don't.

Can someone tell me why? The variable is declared outside the very first function so it sould be available in the rest of the code. I need to parse the HTML-input-file like this because I want to be able to access things like `htmlInput.getElementsByTagName('table')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `htmlInput` variable is being assigned a value after the second `console.log` and `initialisation2` are called. This is because `FileReader` is asynchronous, so `htmlInput` will be `undefined` until the file has been read.

Moving the `initialisation2` call into the `load` callback will resolve this:

```js
reader.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
  inputFile = e.target.result;
  htmlInput = new DOMParser().parseFromString(inputFile, "text/html").documentElement;
  initialisation2();
});
```

We can replicate what is happening using a timeout that mimics the asynchronousity of the file reader:

```js
var htmlInput;

function sefunction() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    htmlInput = "Given htmlInput";
    initialisation2(); // logs "Given htmlInput"
  }, 1000);

  initialisation2(); // logs "undefined"
}

function initialisation2() {
  console.log(htmlInput);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I now changed the load callback so that ```htmlInput``` immediately gets passed into a new function which then assigns its value to a new variable which then can be used everywhere in the rest of my script.